# No route matches {:action=>"show_post_category", :category_id=>5, :controller=>"posts"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While practicing Rails, I have a problem that I am unable to resolve it, it as below:
- I want to show all posts belong to the category (via foreign key category_id) when I clicking on category name, I write a method in 'post' controller:

```
def show_post_category
  if params[:category_id]
    @categories = Category.find_by(params[:category_id])
    @posts = @categories.posts
  else
    @posts= Post.all
  end
end
```

In the view, I write the code to show the category name hyperlink:

```
<% @categories = Category.all %>
<% @categories.each do |c| %>                      
  <li>
    <%= link_to c.name, :controller => "posts", :action => "show_post_category", :category_id => c.id %>
  </li>     
<% end %>
```

However, when I click on category name, the error is displayed

```
'No route matches {:action=>"show_post_category", :category_id=>5,:controller=>"posts"}.
```

Here is the code in routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  resources :categories   
  resources :categories do
    posts do
      get 'show_post_category'
    end
  end 
end
```

Where is the problem in my code ? please give me the solution for this.

Thank you so much,

Comment: `get 'show_post_category'` -> `get '/show_post_category/:category_id'`

Answer (score 0):

```
def show_post_category
    if params[:id].present?
        @posts = Category.find(params[:id]).posts
    else
        @posts= Post.all
    end
end
```

Or even shorter

```
def show_post_category
    @posts = params[:id].present? ? Category.find(params[:id]).posts : Post.all
end
```

Change route: `get 'show_post_category/:id'`

And replace `each` with `map`

```
<% @categories = Category.all %>
<% @categories.map do |c| %>                      
    <li>
        <%= link_to c.name, :controller => "posts", :action => "show_post_category", :id => c.id %>
    </li>     
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you Mikhail Katrin

Answer (score 0):

That sure sounds frustrating!

Maybe you should try specifying that this is a collection from the `routes.rb` file like so:

```
  resources :categories do
    resources :posts do
      collection do
        get 'show_post_category'
      end
    end
  end
```

Let me know how that works for you.

If you want to do a deeper dive here are some more helpful documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thank you so much Schwad, I will reference to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot better.

To create a route that shows all the posts belonging to a category you want the following route:

```
GET /categories/:category_id/posts
```

This is a restful way of declaring a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

You would declare the route by:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :categories, only: :index, module: :posts
end
```

`module: :posts` tells Rails we want to use a  seperate `Categories::PostsController#index` instead of `PostsController`.

```
class Categories::PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category

  # GET /categories/:category_id/posts
  def index
    @posts = @category.posts
  end

  private

  def set_category
    @category = Category.includes(:posts).find(params[:category_id])
  end 
end
```

Using a module here is really optional but its IMHO a superior solution to "param sniffing":

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # and
  # GET /categories/:category_id/posts
  def index
    if params[:category_id]
       @posts = Category.includes(:posts).find(params[:category_id])
    else
       @posts = Post.all
    end
  end
end
```

The later violates the single responsibility principle.

Comment: Thank you Max, I will try with your suggestion and let you know.